# "makeglossaries: Invalid argument" without any arguments

Tags: errors, glossaries, windows

I have a MikTeX installation on a Windows 7, and just downloaded and installed ActiveState Perl to be able to run the `makeglossaries` script.

Unfortunately, something is wrong, since even trying to run it directly from the command line (without any arguments) results in a cryptic error message:

```
makeglossaries: Invalid argument.
makeglossaries: Data: 4294967295
```

I cannot reproduce the error on  my Linux, since running `makeglossaries` on it simply results in `makeglossaries: Need exactly one file argument`, which is a more reasonable and expected message.

TeXMaker is otherwise running fine. What could be causing this, and how can I solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this error was too localized and from a duplicate setup of MikTeX on the O.P.'s machine

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after some time, so in case someone has the same issue...

In fact, there were two installations of MikTeX in the machine, an old one which had not been properly uninstalled, and a more recent one.

Because MikTeX always adds its `bin` directory to the environment path, and the most recent installation is added later, the scripts get confused between the two versions and give the above error message.

Simply removing the old directory from the `Path` variable (and restarting the application if needed to update its environment variables) is sufficient to allow the script to work as expected.

Note: I had previously uninstalled Active Perl and tried replacing it with Strawberry Perl, but after redoing some tests I can confirm both versions work with `makeglossaries`.